# How to write e^(-1000|t|) in matlab title?

Tags: matlab

I wanted to write `e^(-1000|t|)` in matlab title of a plot. When I entered this and ran it actually, it showed ( as a superscript and every thing else in the line in regular font.  Now I wanted the whole thing `-1000|t|` to appear as a superscript.  I tried bracketing etc and finally I achieved what I wanted by inserting ^ before every letter. Is there a better way?

Comment: @ Seetha Rama Raju  I am not sure about |t| but u can write in matlab as 
exp(-1000|t|)

Comment: Thanks.  That I know.  I wanted the power to appear actually as power i.e. superscript.  I could achieve that to with ^ before every letter.  Was asking if there is a better way.

Comment: i don't get u. example for e^(5) in matlab it is exp(5)

Comment: I am not asking about computing e^5.  I am asking about how to write e^(some expression) in title of a plot.

Comment: Try putting braces around everything you want in the exponent: e^{-100|t|)}

Comment: Wow! Wonderful! It worked.  How did you imagine? thanks! I had earlier tried brackets and they did not work.

Comment: I did not imagine, I knew that it was LaTeX like.

Comment: And how is that exactly a Signal Processing question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write e^(-1000*|t|) in Matlab in colored form if you want as

title('\ite^{-1000 |t|}','Color','b') 
Here,"b" is for blue color ,"r" for red,"g" for greeen.

For subscript use _

For superscript use ^

For exponential symbol use \ite ,

For lambda symbol use \lambda

For alpha use \alpha.

Comment: Took time to check, it is working!